# Grabbing a source string from a selected element within an HTML table

Tags: svg, javascript

I have an HTML table which contains various images inside. I would like upon clicking an item within the table a function to be called that changes the source image of another element within my website.

How to grad the id of the clicked image from the table ?

and this is the Javascript function i call upon.

function changeMaterial()

```
    {
    var newsource = document.getElementById("WHAT TO PUT HERE??").src;
    canvas_background.setAttribute("xlink:href", newsource);
    alert("You loaded a new material");

    }
```

what should i use in place of the WHAT TO PUT HERE to get the clicked elements source?

I have ommited all the (>) symbols from my table.
Thanks guys and sorry im a complete amateur!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have something like

```
<td id="foo" onClick="changeMaterial()">My Table Cell</td>
```

I'm guessing.

You'll need to pass something to the changeMaterial function. Either the element id, or the url you want

```
<td id="foo" onClick="changeMaterial(this.id)">My Table Cell</td>
```

and you function will look like

```
function changeMaterial(id) {
    var newsource = document.getElementById(id).src;
    ...
```